# vue filter is not working inside parenthesis

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to render a filtered var inside an alternative if else statement.

```
<span>{{ myVar ? (myVar | date('DATETIME_SHORT')) : '-' }}</span>
```

This gives me an error

```
Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.date is not a function"
```

if I render the var without the conditional statement works

```
<span>{{ myVar | date('DATETIME_SHORT') }}</span>
```

If I remove the parenthesis again it doesn't work

```
{{ myVar ? myVar | date('DATETIME_SHORT') : '-' }}
```

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters have to appear at the end of the expression. The only thing that can come after a filter is another filter.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

> Filters should be appended to the end of the JavaScript expression

If you put a `|` in the middle of an expression it will be treated as the JavaScript `|` operator, bit-wise OR, instead.

You have two options:

1. Define a new filter that includes the conditional. Filters can be defined locally on a component if you don't want to register it globally.
2. Use a method instead.